# Task Parallelism, memory management, and end of task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, memory, task-parallel-library

I have a process that need work on files in parallel, so I am trying to use .net's Task library to accomplish this. I have a class which preforms a task in a static method like so:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(
() => FileProcessor.ProcessAFile(new FileInfo(e.FullPath)));
```

The problem is that it seems that the thread is never deallocated or the memory is never reclaimed once the static method completes. The method is doing some image manipulation so holds on to a large amount of memory, and I watch the process consume about 1 GB of memory before it levels out. Is this the ThreadPool working behind the scenes and determining that 1 GB is the appropriate amount of memory to hold on to, or do I have a deeper memory leak problem?

Comment: "before it levels out." is your answer. Neither ThreadPool nor tasks have anything to do with memory management - it is up to GC to decide when collect memory and how much memory to use.

Comment: If you keep holding a reference to the `Task` after it has completed, the GC may never have a chance to do its work the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think that generating 1GB of memory would take quite some time, so the `GC` probably moved this data to the second/third Generation which are being checked less often than the first Generation and for that reason the data takes some time to be reclaimed. It's probably not a memory leak problem because as you mentioned it eventually levels out.

You could speed up the process by calling [GC.Collect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx), which will force the `GC` to imminently collect data from all of the generations. You need to make sure though the all the references to this chunk of data have been nulled before you call the `Collect` method.